# Magento 1.9 - Use backorder stock instead of actual stock for certain products

Tags: magento-1.9, cataloginventory

For some "**Special**" products in a webshop I want to use Backorder stock instead of actual stock which is available for those products but not sure how to proceed with it.

I have looked into `MAGE_CATALOGINVENTORY_STOCK_ITEM` and its functions `CheckQty()` and `VerifyQty()` but still do not how shall I tell Magento to not use actual stock when I place order for those products. Because I do not want Magento to reduce the stock for them. Also I am not sure if I do it in an **event** or by overriding `MAGE_CATALOGINVENTORY_STOCK_ITEM` class.

I be very grateful if someone can give me ideas or share some code regarding this.

No, I have not written any code so far as I am not sure how to proceed with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The challenge was not to reduce the the product stock if Pre-order mode is selected. As same product can be both Pre and Re-order product. So to keep the stock information same for the product I have to override few function of `cataloginventory_stock_item` class.

The functions which I override are:
`verifyStock`
`subtractQty`
`verifyNotification`

On the other hand one can look into `registerProductsSale` function who subtracts product quantity from stock.

Or can use `subtractQuoteInventory` function of an observer which according to Magento **Also called after every successful order placement to ensure subtraction of inventory**